# Are there any surviving (extant) copies of "the book of the wars of the lord"?

Tags: numbers

In the book of Numbers, Chapter 21 verse 14, a ***book of war*** is mentioned.

many of the books written thousands of years ago have been destroyed.

Were all surviving copies of the ***book of war*** lost over the eons? Are there any fragments in the dead sea scrolls, or any of the older surviving copies of the bible?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Wars_of_the_Lord.  Perhaps it was alluded to in Ex 17:14.

Comment: See Wikipedia lost books of Bible, also on this site Lost books . I don't think there's any surviving copy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no copy or fragment known to exist today.

> The so-called lost books of the Bible are those documents that are mentioned in the Bible in such a way that it is evident they were considered authentic and valuable but that are not found in the Bible today. ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bd/lost-books?lang=eng))

A list of such books can be found [here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bd/lost-books?lang=eng), including the Book of the Wars of the Lord.

It is possible that quotations from this book are preserved in other writings, but without a direct citation (e.g. "I'm quoting X right now") we cannot be sure.

Jerusalem was destroyed multiple times and much Jewish literature was destroyed; we have today but a fraction of what Jewish scribes once wrote.

Comment: Good answer! Also long time no see HTTR. How have you been?

Comment: @Rajesh thanks, good to see you as well!